# Was the "fleet chase" scene inspired by an older naval work?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

The famous "*Death Star Run*" in A New Hope was very much influenced by (some would say copied) the black and white film [The Dam Busters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dam_Busters_(film))

In The Last Jedi we have a sequence where a small fleet of ships is running just out of gun range of a larger one, slowly losing ships and personnel to attrition. This felt to me very much like a naval movie.

**Is there any older naval film that this sequence is obviously inspired by?**

Comment: There are two distinct questions here; "What inspired this sequence" and "why didn't the Star Destroyers do a micro-jump".

Comment: I'm interested in what inspired the sequence, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: The other question/s are perfectly valid. I've edited to make your question more comprehensible and removed some of the "chatter" that was distracting from your key point

Answer (score 1):

I'll risk myself and say, it's a representation of the classical napoelonic era ship chase trope, whose variant "fog chase" can be seen at the beginning of the film of Master and Commander.

[STERN CHASE TV TROPE](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SternChase)

[Master and commander Battle #2 scene, at the end, it's where turns into a long, slow music, night fog chase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E794rTPa4nA)

Althought i would not completely discard a familair movie / documental scene where a  WW2 capital ship fight where landing craft / ships sail away while the almost sunk battleship serves as protection. can't remember where, though.

Maybe the battle of Midway, maybe the sinking of HMS Aboukir, maybe the "landing" operations of the Dardanelles campaings, where many transports and battleships were sunk while the landing craft and transports was still,ehm landing, more importantly at the Anzac Cove, where the HMS Iressistible sunk.

I'm not sure it's a direct concrete movie reference or, rather, the idea of a long, unavoidable, chase for survival unless luck steps in, napoleonic style.
[image]

Comment: I think you may be right, I've been trawling naval movies on Wikipedia, but have not got back as far as Napoleon yet.